# How can I enable MySQL slow query log on my server?

Tags: mysql

How do I enable slow query log on my server? I have enabled it on my local host by adding `log-slow-queries =[path]` in `my.ini` file, but don't know how to add this on my server. My server is Linux-based and has PHP version 5.2.16.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Enabling slow query log has nothing to do with PHP version. You have to enable it in the MySQL server. You can enable in two ways

1. In runtime
2. During the server start

If your server is above 5.1.6 you can set the slow query log in the runtime itself. For which you have to execute this queries.

```
set global log_slow_queries = 1;
set global slow_query_log_file = <some file name>;
```

Or alternatively you can set the this options in the my.cnf/my.ini option files

```
log_slow_queries = 1; 
slow_query_log_file = <some file name>;
```

Where the option file is changed, the MySQL server need to be restarted.

Location of the mysql option file can be found here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-file-location.html

FYI : `log_slow_queries` was removed in MySQL 5.6.1 and `slow_query_log` is used instead.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries

But for performance you can set the log output (option `log_output`) to `TABLE`. 
Also you can have a look other slow query log options like `long_query_time`, `log-queries-not-using-indexes`

Comment: when i am running this query `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 1;` i am getting this error `#1193 - Unknown system variable 'slow_query_log'`

Comment: sry it should be `log_slow_queries`, i will make the necessary edit.

Comment: i run this command also `set global log_slow_queries = 1;` now its showing `#1238 - Variable 'log_slow_queries' is a read only variable`

Comment: What this query result gives SELECT @@version;

Comment: As it is below 5.1.6 so you have to set the log file manually 
Open the my.ini file and put the following line in the ini file 
`log_slow_queryies = 1;
slow_query_log_file = '/var/log/mysql-slow.log'
long_query_time = <some int which represent value more than which the query will be logged in the slow_query_log_file, default is 10sec>`

Comment: And definitly after editing the server you have to restart the MySQL server

Comment: how can i edit this file my.ini ? I don't know how to access this file in server

Comment: This should help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-file-location.html :)

Comment: You will file the my.ini on the system where MySQL server is running.

Comment: @rituparnakashyap: I think you should edit your answer with the above comments. It has become so messy.

Comment: I have no clue how this entry got accepted, but mine below did not. `log_slow_queryies` [sic] is not even spelled correctly, and was deprecated in MySQL 5.1.29. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries

Comment: @RossSmithII : Thanks for pointing out spelling mistake. I have corrected it. :)

Comment: @ Ross Smith II i saw that spelling mistake and i corrected it while doing. I tried to edit that answer but it says `Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters` so i left it.

Answer (score 39):

You can set it temporarily, by running the following commands:

```
set global slow_query_log = 1;
set global slow_query_log_file = '/var/log/mysql-slow.log';
```

but your changes will be undone when mysql is restarted.

You can set it permanently, by adding the following to your `my.cnf` file:

```
slow-query-log=1
slow-query-log-file=/var/log/mysql-slow.log
```

The location of `my.cnf` varies by OS, but is often found in `/etc/my.cnf`, or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

After saving your changes, you will need to restart MySql. This can vary by OS, but here are some common examples:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

and

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Comment: when i am running this query `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 1;` i am getting this error `#1193 - Unknown system variable 'slow_query_log'`

Comment: don't get upset. Since both answers were help full for me i have up-voted both. And i can accept only one answer other wise i would have accepted yours also.I have accepted his answer because he responded to my doubts.

Answer (score 13):

First (as root:)

```
mkdir /var/log/mysql
touch /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/log/mysql
```

Then under [mysqld] in /etc/my.conf (or wherever your configuration file is:)

```
slow_query_log = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
long_query_time=1
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
```

Next:

```
service mysql restart
```

Finally:

```
mysql
mysql> SELECT SLEEP(10);
mysql> quit
```

Verification:

```
cat /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log

/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.42-cll (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started with:
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: (null)
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 150727  0:05:17
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 10.000215  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1437973517;
select sleep(10);
```