# MySQL: help finding query which take too long to execute

Tags: mysql, terminal, processlist

How to find the MySQL query which take too long to execute (more than 5 sec)?

I tried using `PROCESSLIST` but its showing minimum info. I need the full query currently running in the server so i can try optimizing the queries to decrease my server load.

Is there any terminal command available to find the currently processing query?

Comment: Did you try [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606972/how-can-i-enable-slow-query-log-on-my-server?rq=1

Comment: thanks Jan Dvorak.
i tried it . but it shows all queries which executed through mysql . but i need to isolate the queries which are running more than a sec

Comment: thanks inhan .
am expecting like a terminal command which will show the current processing queries which is taking more than a sec .
explain will not be useful in my case

Comment: if you log slow queries as suggested, you can set minimum time of slow query with parameter long_query_time. If you set value to 5, then it should log all queries which take more than 5 seconds to execute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see full query from SHOW PROCESSLIST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638689/how-to-see-full-query-from-show-processlist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 5.1+, the slow query log can be used. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) is documentation. The configuration and running options are related to MySQL version. But I believe you can achieve your goals following the instructions related to your environment.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to go as you can specify your requirements. I personally use [Monyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog) due to its ease of use and amount of data it provides. If you are not looking to buy a tool. You can download a 14 day trial to sort this particular issue.