# MySQL General Logging

Tags: mysql, logging

How can I set MySQL server to start by default with:

- log_output  set to TABLE
- general_log  enabled
- slow_query_log enabled
- long_query_time set to 1s

If this can be done in phpMyAdmin that would be great.

Comment: All this is in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

Comment: Proof would be helpful.  I looked but didn't find it.

Comment: As an example, please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606972/how-can-i-enable-slow-query-log-on-my-server) question