# Docker container with MySQL not writing in the log file

Tags: mysql, centos, docker

I am working on an existing `Dockerfile` that I have been asked to modify as less as possible. The docker image is based on a CentOS Linux image and is supposed to contain a MySQL service.

I want to enable the verbose logging for all the queries (i.e. `general_log` and `general_log_file` variables on the `/etc/my.cnf` file).

The MySQL service needs to be run in the `mysqld_safe` mode and I've checked that the configuration lines I am adding (see below the `printf`) are after the `[mysqld_safe]` line in the `/etc/my.cnf` file, so I am assuming this setting should be fine.

What I've done so far is adding to the `Dockerfile` the following statements:

```
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql

# [...] Lots of Mysql stuff regarding importing DBs etc.

# Adding some more configuration details to the database service
RUN printf '\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n' '# Set General Log to log all the queries' 'general_log=1' 'general_log_file=/var/log/mysql_general.log' >> /etc/my.cnf

# Getting the new log file prepared to get written by the MySQL service
RUN touch /var/log/mysql_general.log
RUN chown mysql.mysql /var/log/mysql_general.log

# MySQL Port
EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT ["mysqld_safe"]
```

After building the docker image and running the docker container I see this in the `/var/log` folder:

```
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql mysql   5108 Nov 20 17:07 mysqld.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 mysql mysql   3880 Nov 20 17:44 mysql_general.log
```

If I grep the `mysqld.log` for keywords like `ERROR` or `general` I can not find anything interesting. The `mysql_general.log` file is empty.

I see this also this:

```
mysql> show variables like '%general_log%';
+------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                      |
+------------------+----------------------------+
| general_log      | OFF                        |
| general_log_file | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.log |
+------------------+----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I am not able to get the SQL queries written in the log file, why?

Comment: Can you show us the output of your mysql error log? Btw: `RUN chown mysql.mysql /va...` has to be `RUN chown mysql:mysql /va...`. You have to seperate user and group by ":".

Comment: I've updated the details. The command `chown` with the dot `.` works fine for me, I don't know why. Thanks

Comment: this may help `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql`