# Cannot log in to the MySQL server error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, osx-yosemite

Sorry for posting this error which has been posted so many times and on multiple forums.

I'm having a hard time resolving this issue. `OSX Yosemite, 10.10`
I installed `mysql` using `home brew`. Can log into mysql as

`mysql -u root -p` The password is null.

Then I ran

`mysqladmin -u root password ''` , ie `null` password for mysqladmin.

I did `localhost/~username/phpmyadmin/setup` to get `config.inc.php` I edited it with

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = TRUE;`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;`

I uninstalled and installed again mysql with homebrew, did all steps again, removed `*.err` file which gave *socket* error.

I tried user `root` with password `mysql`, ``, `password`, `my_machine_password`
Not a single thing works.!

In `config.inc.php` I've following setting:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';`

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`

I `restart` apache everytime.
What am I missing?

Nothing seems to let me through it. All posts direct to same steps I've been doing, yet nothing is able to get pass this **harrowing** process.! 
Kindly help..

Comment: Can you post the exact errors you're running up against?

Comment: `Cannot log in to the MySQL server` error in red dialog box on phpmyadmin page. :(

Comment: Hmm that doesn't tell us much, does it? What about the "socket" error you mention?

Comment: Do you have any log with the `MySQL` errors?

Comment: That is the only message it displays. I'm able to go through mysql on command line. But not through localhost thing.

Comment: @mopo922 Socket error is when you uninstall mysql, and do not remove/delete  `*.err mysql` file in `/var/some_location`

Comment: @D4V1D Could you please tell how to find `mysql` log file?

Comment: I'd check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql

Comment: I found `**my.cnf**` at `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.23`

I do not have `my.cnf` at `/etc`

Comment: Still no success. When I run `mysqladmin -uroot -prootpass status` I get an output like

`Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Uptime: 199  Threads: 1  Questions: 18  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 67  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 60  Queries per second avg: 0.090`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here's the thing which haunted me for hours. I didn't find this on on any tutorials there. But I found this on youtube videos.
When you `brew install mysql`, you will have null as your password. You can change if you'd like to.

But also do following:

Step 1:
**`sudo mkdir /var/mysql`**

Step 2:
**`sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock`**

Step 3:
restart your mysql.server

Now follow phpmyadmin setup instructions. You should be able to get in with your root username, and password.