# MySQL Server Logs

Tags: mysql

I would like to know about MySQL Server Logs files.

1. All log file names.
2. The path of storing all log files in windows.
3. Use MySQL command prompt to see
4. Restore log files

Regards.
Ganesh Prasad

Comment: That is an extremely lazy question. [Googling "MySQL Server logs"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=mysql+server+logs) gives you plenty of results, including the official documentation, and including SO questions like [How to see log files in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql). Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: You can find most of (all?) the answers in the documentation. The page [5.1.2 Server Configuration Defaults](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html) is a good starting point.