# How to Delete MySQL Log File

Tags: mysql

I am using Windows 7 and My Computer Name is 'COREI5' and have a 1tb Hard Drive.

My Hard Drive is showing as Full but i was not able to Locate which File is so huge to Block the Drive Space.Now Seems i Figured out the File Source.

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\COREI5-PC-slow

So it seems this 'COREI5-PC-slow' is the culprit file as it is showing a size of aprox 640GB.Note that this filw is shown as a txt file.

My queries are:
1) Will deleting this file harm my computer ? (I am getting error "You Need permission from Computer administrator to make changes")

2) I am not able to delete this file (even after i logged in as administrator)
3) Also Tried to give special permissions but now working

Any Solution ?

Note: I am not much savvy with Such Programs and commands to request you to give details or keep it simple.

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the file is the "slow query" log in the MySQL data directory.

To confirm, connect to MySQL database, and run a query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'slow%'


Variable_name        Value                                                         
-------------------  --------------------------------------------------------------
slow_launch_time     2                                                             
slow_query_log       OFF                                                           
slow_query_log_file  C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server\MyLaptop-slow.log
```

I suspect that in your case, `slow_query_log` is set to `ON`. If the filename shown for `slow_query_log_file` matches the file on your system, you can safely turn off the slow_query_log and then delete the file.

To turn off the slow query log:

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 0
```

Re-run the SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'slow%' to confirm it's off.

And then you can delete the file from the filesystem. (If you are doing it from the GUI, don't just Delete the file and put it the Recycle Bin. Hold down the shift key when you click Delete, and it will prompt you if you want to "permanently" delete the file.

I'd be concerned that MySQL has logged 640GB worth of slow queries.

That slow_query_launch_time determines the amount of time a query executes before it's considered slow. There also may be a setting that sends all queries that don't use an index into the slow query log, even if it runs faster than slow_query_launch_time.

While you're at it, check that the general log is turned off as well.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general%'
```

This question might better be asked on dba.stackexchange.com

---

For hunting down huge space consumers, I recommend TreeSize Free from JAM Software. An easy to use old-style windows explorer interface, that gives you the total size of directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

My final objective was to delete that file stated above and i was able to achieved the same with help of SHIFT+DELETE and then restart of PC.

It worked - thank you once again.