# mysql 5.7 log-slow-queries error

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm trying to enable Slow Query Logging on mysql 5.7 and getting this error:

2016-04-27T14:55:51.934612Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-query.log'

2016-04-27T14:55:51.934639Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

In my /etc/my.cnf file I have "log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-query.log" defined, but I'm going to assume that in 5.7 that is invalid. What is the correct my.cnf settings to enable query logging?
Thanks,

Comment: Version 5.1.29 deprecated that syntax (and some other log syntax); 5.6.1 removed it.  What was generating it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Name of the MySQL system variable is **`slow_query_log_file`**

And to enable it, you need to set **`slow_query_log` to ON or 1**

[**MySQL Reference Manual: sysvar_slow_query_log_file**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file)

[**MySQL Reference Manual: sysvar_slow_query_log**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log)

Comment: Does slow query also mean "All queries"? My overall goal is to enable logging of all queries, yet all I see are comments about slow queries. There isn't some other flag for enabling all queries, is there?

Comment: The **`general_log`** can log everything. And it can grow really fast. We only enable it temporarily for debugging. Reference: [**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html)

Comment: Have many awnsers in Stackoverflow using `log-slow-queries` to set the path... Thank you for the anwser.

Answer (score 29):

***log-slow-queries*  is deprecated**

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html

```
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow-queries.log
long_query_time = 1
```

Comment: The defaults in 5.7.20 as of this comment are incorrect. You'll have to update it manually as stated above.

Comment: Also on `mysqld` command, it's now `--slow-query-log`, and NOT `--log-slow-time`