# Where is the mysqld event log?

Tags: mysql, logging

When I run `mysqld`, it has a whole lot of information about what it's doing.

As I understand, this is not the correct way to run a mysql server and you should use `service mysql start` instead (on older servers at least).

Any searches for mysqld log come up with logs for queries, I want to know what the program is doing as it starts. (I'm trying to set up mariadb 10.1.14 with galera replication)

I want to be able to run `service mysql start` and then watch what's happening in the background.

Comment: You can try running it verbose `mysqld --user=mysql --verbose`

Comment: Running `mysqld` shows the correct amount of information. However, I want to see this info after I run `service mysql start`. Service only shows `Starting MySQL....... [FAILED]`

Comment: Did you check your mysql config file? There you should find your desired log location. [Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql)

Comment: I have and the config I have doesn't specify where the log should be.

Thanks for that, I must have been misinterpreting the error_log to be a query error log. I found it in /var/log/mysqld.log.