# PHP MYADMIN SQL BACKUP LOG HISTORY

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin I have executed a simple query like

```
select * from table1;
```

now from export option of phpMyAdmin exported into sql format as backup data. In this case from where i can find this track that i have taken backup of this data-set.

Comment: There's no such feature whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you must see separate database named 'mysql'. In this database you will find a table called 'general_log'.

If your MySQL log is enable then you will find logs in this table.

Open your my.cnf file.

```
[mysqld]
# Set Slow Query Log
long_query_time = 1
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /usr/log/slowquery.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1

#Set General Log
general_log = on
general_log_file=/usr/log/general.log
```

Be careful though - enabling the general log can place a heavy load on your server. To be used sparingly for short periods/debugging only.

Answer (score 0):

I would enable SQL logging and check them (not in phpmyadmin).

For mysql, it's not enabled by default, see [How to see log files in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql)