# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS not working and have no error

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**

By right `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table` query should be working since it work in live project. However it's not able to create new table after setup.

I have checked mysql error log, error do not exist. 
Not able to find mysql error - ( refer [How to see log files in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql) )

My Setup

- MySQL Version 5.5.0
- MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
- Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) PHP/5.6.25
- MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id$
- phpMyAdmin Version information: 3.4.6

**Solution** : Do not include `sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO$`
in `my.cnf` file.
One of the command here cause problem, but at last it's work after removed it.

Comment: How do you execute this query? What is the value of `$table`?

Comment: there isn't enough code to support the question, this in regards to "php" - check for errors via php and the query. You may be trying to create the same table.

Comment: Please add your php code. We cannot help without that.

Comment: Fred-ii- there is no exact same table name. Because I will check whether table name exist in database. 
Qirel $table is table name I want to create

Comment: @arkascha I guess it's not code problem. Since it work in live. Other developer working as well. I just want to know anyone face same problem with me. Or I may misconfigure something.

Comment: Then this question makes little sense, sorry. It is pretty obvious that the MySQL feature `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` _does_ work, otherwise the Internet would be _full_ of bug reports and questions.

Answer (score 0):

> $table is table name I want to create

I believe then your SQL statement would be like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
```

Well that's total wrong cause you are completely missing the table definition. Means the column names, their datatype and size at bare minuimum even if you don't want to create any constraint right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create table without column.

Try this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

This query successfully created table "$table".