# Need to see mysql log with jailed ssh access

Tags: mysql, logging

I've been searching around for a software which enable to see live mysql log for each queries made on wordpress or any site uses mysql.

Can anybody give me a suggestion ? I'm using linux mint & mac.

Thank you.

Comment: tail -f path/mysql.log i dont know where exactly is the mysql log file, but i know tail -f. That display the content of a given file and automatically updates the screen when the file changes its content

Comment: I have tried tail -f path/mysql.log and click button & update form on the website but no logs came up on the terminal.

Comment: Thats maybe because you dont have logs activated. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql . Hope it helps!