# MySQL not running

Tags: mysql, c9.io

I am busy creating a website on c9 and all of a sudden it stopped responding. I used `service mysql status` to check if it running and it says MySQL Stoopped but I didn't do anything to MySQL to make it stop.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it keeps saying fail. Please help me

Comment: Have you checked the logs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql

Comment: I sould probably mention that I am using Wordpress

Comment: What's the EXACT error that it gives on the fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `mysql-ctl start`.

For the command line try, `mysql-ctl cli`.

Happy coding!

[Image of command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAcBk.png)

[Image of command line command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZnhQ.png)