# How do I get mysql logs at a certain time?

Tags: mysql, sql

So i forget to save when data get input(timestamp) for my table and now i need to query to get data from a certain time range.

is there a way to get the log / data (date/timestamp) the data is entered into the table?

I use MySQL for the database.

I need log of query that already executed long time ago.

Comment: If you didn't enter the date/time information into the table there is no way to retrieve it. MySQL tables don't have an implicit timestamp recording function.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see log files in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql)

Comment: it only affects new query when the log active right?