C# MySQL Connector/Net 9.0.0 - Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts
I will need your advice here, because I am really stuck.
I am trying to connect to MySQL from my local computer to server (LAN).
MySQL Version is 8.0.39
Target framework is .NET 4.8
public bool TestConnection()
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = Program.settings.MySqlServer,
            Port = Convert.ToUInt32(Program.settings.MySqlPort),
            UserID = Program.settings.MySqlUser,
            Password = Program.settings.MySqlPass,
            Database = Program.settings.MySqlDBName,
            //SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Disabled,
            //ConnectionProtocol = MySqlConnectionProtocol.Tcp,
            //Pooling = true
        };

        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Program.ErrorLog(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}


I got this error:

Message Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

With InnerExeptions

Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
operation or the server is not responding.
The operation has timed out.

  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException was caught
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
  Source=MySql.Data
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Code=0
  Number=1042
  StackTrace:
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.<OpenAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.<OpenAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.<CreateAsync>d__74.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.<CreateAsync>d__74.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.<CreateNewPooledConnectionAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.<GetPooledConnectionAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.<TryToGetDriverAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.<GetConnectionAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__94.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
       at ClickCardService.MySQL.Connection.TestConnection() in c:\Team_Click\ClickCardService\ClickCardService\MySQL\Connection.cs:line 103
  InnerException: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
       Source=MySql.Data
       ErrorCode=-2147467259
       Code=0
       Number=0
       StackTrace:
            at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.<GetTcpStreamAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.<GetStreamAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.<OpenAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
       InnerException: System.TimeoutException
            HResult=-2146233083
            Message=The operation has timed out.
            InnerException: 

This is the output of the connection string builder
server=192.168.0.21;port=3306;user id=r357;password=Pass1234;database=tidra2

The TCP port is allowed - no firewall issue.
Telnet to the server IP and Port is working.
Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.21 -Port 3306 is working.

ComputerName     : 192.168.0.21
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.0.21
RemotePort       : 3306
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 192.168.0.9
TcpTestSucceeded : True

Also I am able to connect from my local computer to server with phpMyAdmin with those settings:
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'r357';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Pass1234';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.0.21';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

Also tested with older mysql connectors 8.4.0, 8.3.0, 8.0.33.1 - the same result.
In MySql General Log File I see when phpMyAdmin connect

Timestamp, Thread, Command Type, Detail
2024-08-27 15:11:26.279050, 27, Connect, r357@PetarSPC on using TCP/IP

EDIT: After I set my log-error-verbosity = 3 already see the error in the mysql error log

2024-08-28T13:28:58.193475Z 10 [Note] [MY-010914] [Server] Got timeout reading communication packets

B.3.2.9 Communication Errors and Aborted Connections
That means the connector reach the MySQL server... but something goes wrong.
The result after I executed SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Id, User, Host, db, Command, Time, State, Info
'12', 'unauthenticated user', 'PetarSPC:12325', NULL, 'Connect', '2', 'Receiving from client', NULL

Any thoughts on this?

What's the version of MySQL? Try whether TcpClient can connect to the endpoint. Log the complete exception, not just the message.

Check the log files : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql

Use Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString) (or Program.LogError or similar) immediately before cn.Open() and check that everything in the connection string is 100% correct. Run Test-NetConnection 192.168.0.21 -Port 3306 from the same computer running this program and verify that it can connect to the MySQL server on that port.

The exception is thrown at this line, it's a simple call to TcpClient.ConnectAsync, so if the IP and port are correct, you can either try increasing the value of ConnectionTimeout, or your program may be blocked by the firewall.

Your question-title says ".NET 9.0" but your post says "Target framework is .NET 4.8" - both can't be right...

Where/how is your program running? Is it running in an environment or host where it might be prohibited from making outgoing connections?

@Dai that's the version of MySQL Connector/NET, aka MySql.Data: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/9.0.0

PhPMyAdmin provides a web interface for MySQL, meaning it runs in a web server. If PhPMyAdmin can connect to the database, that tells you the web server is able to connect to the database, but it does not mean your local machine is able to connect to the database unless both the web server and your local machine are the same computer. If they are not the same computer, this could still be a firewall issue. Additionally, remember the operating system hosting MySQL has a firewall, and MySQL itself has a separate listing for allowed IPs. Both need to be configured.

One other thing to check is whether there is a fail2ban service protecting MySQL and may have blocked your after a few failed attempts. Oh, and I've also seen antivirus software interfere with outgoing database connections.
